# Deploy from command line using MSBUILD and or MSDEPLOY (.NET 3.5)

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

I'm trying to get my website deployed by a Jenkins job.

I'm using the following command line sentence, with no success:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe" myproj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

I've also tried:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe" myproj.csproj  /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OutputPath="obj\debug" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/demo"
```

None works although my project is compiled properly.

WHen I go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot nothing new is there. I want my site to start running and be accesible from my browser in Localhost.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @OğuzhanTopçu please see my extended description. My site is not being copied to inetpub nor visible from the IIS administration panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MSDeploy to deploy your web app using the following MSBuild arguments

```
/p:Configuration=release
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://targetServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd
/p:DeployIisAppPath=MySite 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:Username=
/p:AuthType=NTLM
```

MSDeploy, however, has proven to be better solution for us.  We use MSBuild to create an MSDeploy package and then we can deploy that package to many environments using MSDeploy.exe.  Build once, deploy many.  Here is an overview of WebDeploy which may be helpful:

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

Comment: I have used the following: ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /t:Package    and that generated a package. However my app is for .NET 3.5 (and only using .NET 4's MBUILD seems to generate the package with no errors). May I now deployit for .NET 3.5 ? How? Thanks

Comment: BTW, if I use the 3.5 version of MSBUILD it throws: error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.

Comment: Yes, you can deploy the package (built via MSBuild 4) to a .NET 3.5 site.  Run the *.deploy.cmd file to deploy the package.  If you run the .cmd file without any params it will provide help documentation.

Comment: It worked, however, I don't see how to deploy for .NET 3.5 when I've used MSBUILT 4...?

Comment: MSBuild 4 is backwards compatible with 3.5 projects.

Comment: But, what happens if I do MSbuild with version 4 and then deploy it on a server that only has .NET 3.5, will that work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are adding the correct parameters after the MSBuild command, such as `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="XXXProfile"`, but the most important is to add the `MSBuild.exe` path to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Having the `MSBuild.exe` path added to your `%PATH%` system environment variable the only thing you need to do is call:
`msbuild myproject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="MyProfile"`, where `MyProfile` is the generated publishing profile with Visual Studio and can be found under `MyProject\Properties\PublishProfiles` folder.